# File transfer service through server that is not P2P, encrypt files without letting the server know its contents

Tags: network, file-encryption

A file transfer tool, that works through a middle man server, as the following diagram:

[image]

`Client A` uploads a file to the server, `Client B` has websocket events that a file is transferring and starts downloading available chunks of the given file.

I would like to encrypt the files without letting the server ever know the file's contents or how to open it, means the private key must not be known by the server.

But is this even possible? How can I let `Client B` know of the key that opens the encryption Client A performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PKI. Each client should publish its public key. When client A wants to send data to client B, it encrypts data using public key of client B and uploads data to the server. Nobody except client B can decrypt such data.

From the technical point of view this should be not a pure asymmetric encryption, but a hybrid one, see:

- [Integrated Encryption Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme)
- [Hybrid RSA and alternatives](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31563/when-why-is-rsa-hybrid-encryption-used-rather-than-alternatives)

Comment: But how will client B get client A's key? the server must not have a chance to have the key even if its just forwarding the requests, and I can't use peer to peer connections

Comment: *"the server must not have a chance to have the key"* - this is not true.  Public key is not secret, it is *public*, everyone is allowed to see it. If you encrypt using **public** key, you **cannot** decrypt using the same key. To decrypt it, you need **private** key. Look what PKI is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure.

Comment: Clients can publish their public key in any suitable way. For instance, they can put it to their own web site and make it available for download for everyone. Or they can send their public key per email - it is *not secret*.

Comment: That actually makes sense, so basically client A gives client B it's public key through the server. Client B uses Client A's public key to encrypt files, and client A opens the files using its private key?

Comment: Yes, you can send public key also via your server. What is important: The key should be not self signed, it should be issued by some CA (certification authority), that is known to both A and B, so that they can verify who has issued that key. Technically speaking, you would send not only the public key, but a *certificate* which contains the public key.

Comment: Do you know if there are any Javascript libraries to encryt/decrypt blob, maybe pki.js ?

Comment: +1  @benberizovsky you can use javascript's native web crypto api to encrypt/decrypt blobs.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API.  Also, see www.encryptedsend.com (I'm the developer) which is similar to what you want to do, but asynchronous and not using websockets.  Last but not least, WRT your question about authenticating keys - PKI is one solution, web of trust is other, or you can use an out of band method - this is what Signal does, they call it 'safety numbers'.  See https://signal.org/blog/safety-number-updates/.

Comment: @mti2935 Thanks mate, nice project you made there. I will try the techniques you described

Comment: @mti2935 Why use PKI over RSA signature ? I can barely find any examples on PKI for web, kind of confusing maybe I am missing something and need to deeply read about how PKI works

Comment: @benberizovsky Client A needs some way of knowing that the public key that he receives for Client B is authentic, and vice-versa.  Otherwise, if the server goes rogue, the server can serve client A a fake public key for Client B (and vice versa), and intercept all of the messages between Client A and Client B.  This is called a Man In The Middle (MITM) attack.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack for more info.  So, RSA signatures (by themselves) are not enough, because the signer's public key is needed to validate the signature...

Comment: @benberizovsky ..and (as explained above) we need a way to authenticate the signer's public key (to eliminate MITM attacks).  This is why we have PKI.  On the web, we have SSL/TLS certificates for this, which are signed by certificate authorities (CA's) like Verisign, LetsEncrypt, etc.

Comment: @benberizovsky: Why do you say *PKI over RSA signature*? You cannot use RSA without PKI. How will A know that particular RSA public key really belongs to the client B? And vice versa: How will B know that particular RSA public key really belongs to A? It is impossible without PKI. To establish trust, public key of A (no matter, RSA or ECC) needs to be signed by some party whom B trusts. Such party is called CA (certification authority). And vice versa: public key of B must be signed by some CA whom A trusts.

Comment: @benberizovsky: To sign a public key there is special data structure named *certificate*. It includes the public key and the signature of the issuer (and some other data like validity period, fingerprint, indicators what this purpose this certificate is allowed to be used for, etc.). These CAs and certificates are elements of PKI.

Comment: Okay so I was a bit confused, PKI is the framework of how you pass the keys in a secure way. But my application is completely web-based, working on top of TLS, so that is not an issue for me, is it? Because the public keys sent to the server are already encrypted with TLS

Comment: @benberizovsky  It's a chicken-and-egg problem.  If the clients don't trust your server with their secrets, then how can they trust your server to relay the correct public keys for one another?  If your server wants to intercept the messages between the clients, it can simply serve fake pubkeys for the clients, and your server will have an MITM position, and can intercept the messages.  TLS doesn't solve this problem.  This is why we have CA's + PKI, or other methods of verifying authenticity of pubkeys, like web of trust (e.g PGP), cert pinning (e.g. SSH), or out of band methods (e.g.Signal).

Comment: Interesting, I understand it now. Do you know where I can read more about it's implementation?

Comment: @benberizovsky: Public keys are not secret. If it fine even to transfer them via HTTP, not HTTPS. The problem is, that the other side *should not trust* any public keys if the are not signed. To sign them, one should use certificates, which CA issues you.

Comment: @mentallurg Does this basically mean that in my case I must use a third-party certificate for this?

Comment: @benberizovsky: There are no such thing as third-party certificates. May be you mean an external CA (certification authority)? The certificates must be trusted by other party. There are 2 approaches for this.

Comment: **Approach 1:** The most systems have some preinstalled trusted CA certificates, like IdenTrust, DigiCert, Sectigo. You request a certificate for client A and for client B from one of these CAs. When client B receives a certificate of A, it sees that it was issued by let say DigiCert CA. Sinse it considers DigiCert CA as a trusted, it trusts that the certificate presented by client A really belongs to A. Thus, it is safe for B to use this certificate to encrypt messages for A.

Comment: **Approach 2:** There are no preinstalled trusted CA certificates, or you don't want to use external CA. Then you can create 2 self-signed certificates, one for A and one for B. Then you install certificate of A on the client B and certificate of B on the client A. Then when B receives a self-signed certificate from A, it sees that this certificate is installed and thus trusted. The same in the other direction.

Comment: @mentallurg Approach 2 requires peer to peer connection to pass each other the certificates, right?

Comment: @benberizovsky: No. Approach 2 requires that there is a secure channel. For instance, you are the owner of client A and client B. If clients A and client B are independent on each other, then only approach 1 is possible: Use some reliable CA.

Comment: @mentallurg What if the server fakes the certificate, signing that it is from DigiCert CA for example, how does this really solve the issue? Do the clients validate the CA by sending a request to the authority's service or something?

Comment: @benberizovsky: Nobody except DigiCert can sign anything as DigiCert. When you install any OS (Windows, Linux, MacOS), a set of certificates of many trusted CAs is installed automatically, too. Then, when client A obtains a certificate of client B issued by let say DigiCert, then client A takes the certificate of DigiCert from its local trust store and checks if the certificate presented by B as really issued by DigiCert. If certificate was issued not by DigiCert, but claimed to be from DigiCert, the check will fail.

Comment: @mentallurg After some research, I don't think PKI solves my issue or I am just not understanding the concept. Even if the server gets CA for A and B through a trusted provider like entrust, letsencrypt, how does the server pass these certificates to the clients A, B? Imagine it, the server can always trick the clients and send them fake public keys or fake made certificates and unlock and data & send encrypted data using the real key to the other client that receives the file. Can you see the complexity there? You can't trust the server at all, the server can perform any trick

Comment: @benberizovsky: I think you don't understand how PKI works. PKI uses asymmetric algorithms. The most important feature of asymmetric algorithms is following: If you have a public key, you cannot compute the private key.

Everyone can easily check if particular signature was done by DigiCert. But except DigiCert itself nobody else can create a signature that shows that it was done by DigiCert.

Comment: @benberizovsky: *"Imagine it, the server can always trick the clients and send them fake public keys or fake made certificates"* - No. This is impossible because of the reason mentioned above. Nobody can fake signature of anyone, because nobody can construct a private key that matches given public key. This is the point.

Comment: @benberizovsky:  *"how does the server pass these certificates to the clients A, B?"* - Certificates are not secret. It is fine, if any intermediate servers or any attackers see the certificates. As I said, since nobody can fake signature, it is absolutely safe to use any public (any unsafe) channels to access or to distribute certificates.